# wp list pages using meta box value

Tags: wp-query, metabox, wp-list-pages

I am using the following meta boxes on services page but how would I get the page(s) which have value of this meta box?

For example, list all pages where service_type = 'web'

I am using the following now...

```
<?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=15&sort_column=ID"); ?>
```

But how would I get pages using meta box value like `$custom["type"][0] == 'web'`?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<?php wp_list_pages("meta_key=type&meta_value=web&title_li=&child_of=15&sort_column=ID"); ?>
```

Note the meta_key and meta_value in the syntax and reuse it.

Comment: sorry for the question, i really missed it, i have got it fixed already, thanks for help anyways.

Comment: can you please help me with 1 more query, above prints list of all pages but how to add meta box values in output.

Comment: You have to call meta boxes with `get_post_meta` or `get_post_custom_values`